# How to print the results of a teradata SHOW statement to a text file so that DDL is executable

Tags: shell, teradata, ddl, teradata-sql-assistant

I would like to write a Teradata bteq script that exports all the DDL for my tables by capturing the output of a show command.  I thought this would be as simple as exporting the results from a show command executed from BTEQ to a file, and that approach worked (see script below) fine on tables without column compression.

The issue is that when there are columns with a large number of compressed values the output wraps and sometimes breaks the line in the middle of compressed values list (e.g. for 'BUSINESS' you get 'BUS and then next line starts with INESS'.  The fact that the compressed values word wrap means that I can't run the exported DDL.

At first I thought that setting the width to a super large number would prevent the word wrapping, but I can't set the width to a large enough value to handle how wide the compressed values string is.  This means that my only option is to run a show statement in Teradata SQL Assistant and copy and paste that one at a time to create my create table DDL script.  I have to think there is a better way to capture the existing DDL in a manner where the exported DDL is executable?

```
#!/bin/ksh
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Environment Variables
LDAP_IND=".logmech LDAP"
TD_UID=uXXXXX
TD_PWD='pwXXXX'
TD_TDPID=TD1
OUT_SCRIPT=./DDL.txt
echo "-----------------------------------"
echo "TD_UID =<${TD_UID}>"
echo "-----------------------------------"

###########################################################################
bteq<<EOBTQ
${LDAP_IND}
.logon ${TD_TDPID}/${TD_UID},${TD_PWD}
.IF ERRORCODE>0 THEN .GOTO ABEND
--#  START  SQL ###########################################################

.set width 999
.export report file=${OUT_SCRIPT}
.set defaults
.set format off
.set foldline on 1,2,3,4
.set sidetitles off
--  IS WIDTH MAX ENOUGH TO ALWAYS ACCOMODATE ALL COMPRESSED VALUES?
.set width 65531

-- Export DDL for Tables Using Show Commands
show sel * from DB_PRODUCTS.t_product_ref;

show sel * from DB_PRODUCTS.t_acct;

--#  FINISH SQL ###########################################################
.LABEL GOODEND;
.QUIT;
.LABEL ABEND;
.QUIT ERRORCODE;
EOBTQ
```

Comment: After experimenting with the width you can go all the way up to 65,631 characters which may be enough to accommodate most compression lists... I am still curious if there is a better approach but setting this absolute max should make it work most of the time using .set width 65531

Comment: `dbc.tvFields.CompressValueList` is defined as `VARCHAR(8192)`, thus you can't have a larger list.

Comment: Thanks so much!  Turns out my text editor (UltraEdit) was doing a soft wrap at around 4k characters which made it look like it was still wrapping, but when I put the line numbers on realized it was a soft wrap/not hard.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that upping the width to the max character value for the CompressValueList will ensure that the out put file can accommodate the full width of the compressed values text without the wrap.  This means that .set width just needs to be 8193 to solve the problem.   Warning to any ultra edit users, some editors have a "soft wrap" where the line appears wrapped but isn't.

Comment: Must be a more than 8193 as there's also column name, data type and maybe constraints.